# How do you put h3 tag on top of h6 tag to fit in within the container?

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  overflow: auto;
  font-family: Arial, helvetica, Sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.container {
  margin: 50%;
  width: 324px;
  height: 495px;
  border: 10px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  /* Setup */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 70%;
}

.container .child2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="child">
    Improve your front-end skills by building front-end projects
  </h3>

  <h6 class="child2">
    Scan the QR code to visit Front-end Mentor and take your coding skills to
    the next level
  </h6>
</div>
```

In the code snippet above h3 text is below h6 text , although i would want h6 text to be nicely fit under h3 text in the container

This becomes a problem. Should I remove h6 heading to paragraph txt so that it will perfectly under h3 tag?

Need some advice

Comment: what you are asking is breaking the rule of html tags . The h6 should be the children tag of h3 not adjacent to it

Comment: An `h6` should never follow an `h3`. Don't use different heading levels for styling. Headings should only be used to semantically mark up document structure. You should not skip headings. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements

Answer (score 0):

`h3` tag and `h6` are side by side because you are using `flexbox` and by default `flexbox` elements are aligned in `row`

what you can do is to bring `h6` under `h3` is you can use another `div` container and make it `flex` and change its direction to column `flex-direction: column`

here is the updated code

```css
* {
  
    margin:0;
    padding:0; 
     
    overflow: auto; 
    font-family: Arial, helvetica , Sans-serif; 
    
  }
  
  
  body {
  
      background-color: aliceblue;
  }
  
  .container {
     
      
         
          margin: 50%;
          width: 324px;
          height: 495px;
          border: 10px solid white;
          border-radius: 20px;
          /* Setup */
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          background-color: white;
      
  }
.content{
          margin-top: 70%;
          display:flex;
          flex-direction:column;
}

  .child {

          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          text-align: center;
          

  }
  
   .container .child2 {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
     margin-top:10%;
/*     margin-top: 100%; */


  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      
  <h3 class="child"> Improve your front-end skills by building front-end projects 
    
  </h3> 


  <h6 class="child2"> Scan the QR code to visit Front-end Mentor and take your coding skills to the next level</h6>
  
    </div>
    
  </div>
```